# Some US AAA Corp are borrowing below UST for 10yr paper. What could be the reasons for this?

Tags: fixed-income, bond-yields

Any particular situations which can lead to this?

Comment: They are considered to be more financially stable that the US government. They are considered to have lower volatility than US treasuries thus a lower risk premium. They are smaller quantities of the issues and greater demand leading to higher prices and lower yields.

Answer (score 1):

I can’t find any today.  Johnson and Johnson is rated AAA and the 10yr yield is Treasury +29bp.  There may have been a time during the debt ceiling drama where very short dated corporate paper traded better than Treasury bills, since the latter were potentially subject to a payment delay.